# How do I redirect from an existing file?

Tags: files, redirection

I have the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module installed, but when I add a redirect from an existing file to a new file, the redirect doesn't activate.

I did some digging and found a post suggesting that Drupal can't redirect a file if it already exists, it can only redirect from 404 or pages. Is this true? Is there really no way to redirect from an existing file?

And if it is true, how do I delete the file? There doesn't seem to be a way to delete a file once it is uploaded. The file was originally attached to a content item but that content has since been deleted.

Comment: Check "Delete orphaned files after ..." in /admin/config/media/file-system

Comment: Yes, that is checked and has been.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redirect rules in .htaccess that cause Drupal to be fired up only happen if/when an actual file doesn't exist. For example, if I have a file in my webroot named file.txt, and I go to example.com/file.txt, Drupal will not start, as the file exists. If that file does not exist, Drupal will be fired up, and show a 404 page (unless you have an alias in Drupal for the path /file.txt). You have said the file exists on your system, which means Drupal is not being started up when someone accesses that file, and therefore the redirect module will not work.

As for how to delete the file, you say the content item has been deleted. This should also result in the file being deleted, though it does not appear that it was. I'd do a search through the {file_managed} table in the database to make sure it's not still in there for some reason - maybe the file is still attached to a different piece of content or something. If you're absolutely sure the file does not exist in Drupal anymore, then you can log into your server (ftp, ssh etc) and manually delete the file.

Comment: The file was originally attached to a content item but that content has since been deleted. Added this to my post.

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Comment: The file is still there. I also tried uploading a PDF to a new page, and then deleting that PDF. The PDF is still accessible despite me deleting it with the Drupal interface. I have Workbench Moderation installed, do you think this is interfering with the deletion?

Comment: By 'still there' you mean still in the database?

Comment: Sorry, still accessible / on the server. I don't have access to view the database until Monday.

Comment: Why wouldn't be - you haven't deleted it!

Comment: It turns out the file wasn't being deleted because of Workbench Moderation. It is saved in a revision history, despite the original page being deleted. Seems to be a bug with the Workbench Moderation module.